# Import .csv into Magento Can not find required columns: sku

Tags: magento, csv, import

We have been programming an application for the next two weeks to make a valid csv file to import to Magento.
But, we have a problem with importing in general, as we get the error that Magento can't find the required columns: sku. I've been looking through a lot of forums.
 I have seen it could be the visibility but we have that in our csv. I will give you an example of how our csv looks like:

```
sku,name,ean,manufacturer,price,msrp,tax_class_id,qty,_category,is_in_stock,status,description,_type,visibility,_attribute_set,color,geluidssysteem,platform_consoles,protection,connection,kabel_lengte,lader,nintendo_platform,model,megapixels,geschikt_foto_video_tas,schermdiagonaal,size,keyboard_layout,geheugen,draagstijl_headset,materiaal,type_camera,type_toetsen,left_right_handed,vermogen,toetesenbord_verlicht,sensorkeuze,stroom_voorziening,connection_mouse,
MRM-01855,AA FUSION AUDIO 3.5mm to 3.5mm Jack kabel 1 meter wit,5060166512163,Advanced Accessories,3.18,,2,6,Nintendo/Nintendo bundels,1,1,Boomsjors,simple,4,PC kabels,Green,,,,Universal,1.8 Meter,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,120w,,,,,
```

We also had the problem that the description contains a comma and then messes up our csv.

If you need any more information, let me know!

Comment: are you using default magento importing functionality?

Answer (score 5):

Please make sure you are using the utf-8 encoded file format for your .csv file. This error occurs mostly with wrong formated file content. 
To make it correct please open your .csv file in editor and go to 'Save As'-> Select File Type as '**MSDOS CSV(.csv)**' and save.

Hope this will help...